# Is it possible, for any $n$, to find the greatest common factor of all highly composite numbers $\geq n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Let's say we have some positive integer $n$ and a set $S$ that is the set of all highly composite numbers greater than or equal to $n$. Is it possible to prove that all members of $S$ share a factor other than $1$? Since it's fairly trivial to prove that all HCN are even other than $1$, is it possible to prove that all members of S have a greatest common factor greater than $2$? If so, is there some method that can be utilized to find the GCF of $S$ for any arbitrarily large $n$? Additionally, can it be proven that there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $\text{GCF}(S)\geq m$ for an arbitrarily large positive integer $m$?

Empirically, I have found possible correlations, such as the observation that if $n=6$, it appears that $\text{GCF}(S)=6$. It also appears that if $n=840$, $\text{GCF}(S)=420$.

Comment: Yes, since highly composite numbers have highly constrained prime factorisations one can find the $\gcd$ of all highly composite numbers $\geqslant n$, but the factorisation isn't rigid enough for it to be easy (once $n$ is somewhat large). Find the smallest HCN $\geqslant n$, and then figure out how low the exponents of the used primes can drop for larger HCNs. And yes, we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} \operatorname{GCF}(S_n) = +\infty$. That's much easier to show than computing the value for some large $n$.

Comment: You could search the site for highly composite and find a number of questions that will help your understanding.  There are also references in http://oeis.org/A002182.  A good heuristic based on the small ones is to look at the next dozen in the list and see if any prime factors drop out.  If not, they are unlikely to drop out later on as the exponent on each prime is generally increasing.